# As a US citizen can I go to the US and sign up for obamacare for a short period of time?

Tags: us-citizens, health-insurance, health

I did research and I don't see why this wouldn't work.

I would like to preface this with the fact that I do have insurance, in fact great insurance that covers the entire world except the USA, and I seem to have something that doctors here in China are having a very hard time treating and is very rare.

So my question is whether I can apply for obamacare in California as a resident of california (my mom lives there), go for a month, get treated, and then cancel my plan.

Comment: If your insurance covers the whole world expect the US, wouldn't that leave a lot of alternative places where you can get treated? (Europe, Australia etc.) or is it only treated in the US?

Comment: Yeah well... I sent out emails and calls to hospitals all around the world.  You would be amazed how few responded.  I really just don't know what to do.  I was in France before, they scoffed at me and told me it was in my head.  Finally 2 months later, doctors in china found a superbacteria hiding away and causing my woes.  In china and france I dealt with the most incompetent doctors again and again and I just want to see some competent ones finally.

Answer (score 6):

Not really.

You can only apply during the open enrollment period (in [California](http://www.coveredca.com/) - runs from November till February), and you commit for the year. You can only make changes mid-year if some [specific events](https://www.healthcare.gov/glossary/qualifying-life-event/) occur.

Also, you may tie yourself to California tax-wise by doing this, which means you'll be exposed to the California income taxes (about 10%) in addition to the Federal income tax you're already exposed to. Note that the California taxes do not conform to the Federal earned income exclusion, foreign tax credit or tax treaty exclusion rules.